# How do I connect to a remote Windows server with no domain in the user name?

Tags: rdp

Someone has given me credentials to a server
Computer name
Username
password

But when I try to connect Remote Desktop Connection, it appends MicrosoftAccount\Username or [computer name\username.

I have tried localhost\username, .\username, and \username. I do not know the machine name of the server.

How do I send nothing for the domain name in Remote Desktop Connection?

Comment: I'm trying to use this tutorial https://wilsonmar.github.io/rdp/ And it just says 'leave the domain blank'.

Comment: `.\username` should work. If it doesn't, contact that someone who gave you the credentials.

Comment: I really did try that, both .\Username and \Username. But it changes it to Computername\Username